# ACS AEM Commons - Class not found by acs-aem-commons-bundle

Tags: azure-storage, aem, sling, azure-java-sdk

I'm trying to write a custom class in [ACS Commons' MCP Tool](https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/mcp-tools/index.html)

**Including "azure storage" api in "pom.xml" as below:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The build runs fine without any compile errors, but while running the program i'm seeing the below in error logs:

**Sample usage:**

```
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount;
..
public class AzureAssetIngestor extends AssetIngestor {
  private CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
  ..
  storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
```

**Error in logs while executing the program**

*Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount not found by com.adobe.acs.acs-aem-commons-bundle*

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount not found by com.adobe.acs.acs-aem-commons-bundle [521]
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1574)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of dependencies for AEM projects:

1. Compile time dependencies
2. Runtime dependencies

In Maven you define *compile time* dependencies. So adding dependencies to your `pom.xml` will make them available only during the build (compile time) by Maven.

It is your job as a developer to make sure that those dependencies are also available during runtime. There are basically three ways to achieve that:

1. Install those dependencies by hand
2. Add those dependencies to a content package that is deployed during your build
3. Embed the dependency to your bundle during build time

It is probably obvious, but you should go with option 2 or 3. Both approaches have their advantages and disadvantages. A (relatively) big issue with option 2 is that not all your dependencies are OSGi bundles. Therefore, for this to work, you would need to transform them to OSGi bundles. This is no rocket science but another thing to keep in mind. Embedding your dependency is easier but I personally do not like that solution that much.

Comment: I am embedding the dependency under as <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId><Import-Package>com.microsoft.azure.*;resolution:=optional,</Import-Package> but still the issues.

Comment: All resolution:=optional means here is that the absense of this package from another bundle does not prevent this bundle from being activated. This is a fine solution if the functionality is optional. It does not, however, obviate the need to actually have that package available (i.e. provided by a different bundle) if the consuming class is used.

Answer (score 0):

With @Jens inputs, the option to install bundles manually helped/worked.

Here's the solution:

**pom.xml**

```
<artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <Import-Package>
    com.microsoft.azure.*;resolution:=optional,
  ...
  </Import-Package>
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-storage</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then go to AEM Bundles (Like http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles) to install bundles manually. You can use either of the below.

**Option 1:**

1. Install [Oak Blob Cloud Azure](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/jackrabbit/oak-blob-cloud-azure/1.9.8/oak-blob-cloud-azure-1.9.8.jar) bundle. The bundle comes embedded with Azure-Storage 5.0.0 package

**Option 2:**

1. Install Apache Service Mix - Download bundle [Azure Storage 8.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.azure-storage/8.0.0_1). This has Azure-Storage 5.0.0 embedded. but has the below dependencies.
2. Guava 20 - Download bundle [guava-20.0.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/20.0/guava-20.0.jar) (Dependency for 1)
3. Jackson Core - Download bundle [jackson-core-2.9.3.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.9.3/jackson-core-2.9.3.jar) (Dependency for 1)